# Meaning of そう in そう、とんでもないことをさらっと言ってのけた

Tags: meaning

> 「て、ていうかっ、鍵閉めてたのに、どうやって入ったんですかっ！」
>
> 「うん？　鍵？あぁ、それなら私、合いカギ持ってるから」
>
> **そう**、とんでもないことをさらっと言ってのけた。

I read this and it looks like he is saying "yes", but I'm not really sure.

Looking at the definitions [here](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E7%84%B6%E3%81%86/#jn-127918)

［副］

１ そのように。「私も然う思う」

２ （あとに打消しの語を伴って）それほど。そんなに。「然う大きくない」

［感］

１ 相手の言うことに肯定・同意するときに用いる語。「然う、そのとおり」

２ 相手の言葉に対する問い返しや、半信半疑の気持ちを表すときに用いる語。「あら、然う」「然う、信じられないな」

３ 過去の出来事を思い出すときなどに用いる語。「然う、あれは去年の夏のことだ]

I think it must come under one of the definitions below ［感］ however #1 does not seem correct.

Comment: "So said she..."

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that your whole snippet is only one person talking. They are quoting others, but it's one person.
So my guess would be (1), そのように.
"Just like that, they blurted out such an unthinkable thing."